# SBT how to use shading to ensure AWS library uses old version of netty, while project uses latest?

Tags: scala, sbt, netty, sbt-assembly

We have a build file with

```
val awssdk2 = "2.15.14"
val netty = "4.1.91.Final"

...
      "software.amazon.awssdk" % "kinesis"      % Versions.awssdk2,
      "io.netty"               % "netty-buffer" % Versions.netty
```

Now this version of the awssdk pulls in `4.1.46.Final` of netty, which gets evicted by `4.1.91.Final`, which breaks some of the awssdk (some dodgy bug or incompatibility in Netty).  (It causes `java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException`)

We want to tell `sbt` to "shade" netty in the awssdk so that calls to awssdk result in calls to the `4.1.46.Final` version of netty, and calls to everything else in the project (like our own netty code, or other libraries that use netty) use `4.1.91.Final`.

Now we know we can bump the awssdk2 version and get things working that way, but this SO is only showing a tiny fragment of a very large build file, and we need a general mechanism of making libraries use their own versions of things.

Perhaps we don't fully understand what shading is supposed to do, but anyway we tried this:

```
    assemblyShadeRules in assembly ++= Seq(
      ShadeRule.rename("io.netty.**" -> "aws2_version_of_netty.@1")
        .inLibrary("software.amazon.awssdk" % "kinesis" % Versions.awssdk2)
    ),
```

and it has no impact - same error.

Comment: Shading is often a nightmare to manage. Do you really need latest Netty version? If not, I would rather use `dependencyOverrides` to enforce specific version is used.

Comment: Thanks @GaëlJ I'm not familiar with `dependencyOverrides`, I'll take a look!